# Customs Legends using to select components

Tags: legend, vega-lite

Why when hovering over the bottom "legend" every time only one of the entries or the last one is highlighted. Is there a way to highlight all components which have same color?

Or like using legend to cross-filter with other visuals also in Deneb. Because I want like when one component is selected in the legend it should highlight timeline and cross-filter other visuals.

[Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-aTmcnRdrIV3SL2f8SxE-Ravmy-o9aUCiiVw58FX5oypEfG1aitRj0HqDbijQSs428wWW9Tg6XGehrDNq7aZm2ub63rnPgHRdvvSGu0Cm73mgPGtf1Zr0TqJ2mpxnCXuc3KFx7W6eTgBdU4QEwNokFkCAADM2DaBAjFACCaEEa02jQeCaDgQQLgXJRQNkMgtmMEAAE84A1NBASUBA5HoapAjqClUEKR0SLI0ojko6iYFosh6OtNALE8Y5AMdMg2jYBgcCYIijAHf8lAAdxoWRlDYeS4JANgcHMKBxNkTB7AQjCLmdJQkAMdAdIYPTOmdISWmg-TUEIwzMPMMwhMdKAdCgBhBAYlQ1AYBBKEs6zTHcABqdwAHIAA9UBiyL3FUTAgsMaLlGi-9bnMkBRPEnAlJ4uy1RwJAoCKtAxCUYgdNkLzHMIxTlBo8FoiUOB6rYZRKs0YjUJAFyLiqJRMCInAdWgnrZB0ewekwQQtlkXzBFM2KaHM0A-KYDCAGE2EEaDzCYPyoAAa3pY4gL8kiUKc0AytAhBzMImaxwwGgyBgYQvv0loMMmRzQDGibzBwNglL+jT5HQKiGAgOA2FIFCrrLN7JsKnSEC0-7FqgIHgPGnVwchgz0Mwl7ZKApglIuRb8OU+k5JAZA2guvqQZ1JgyJRMSzq506LqAzqdOmni+tigahvMFBRqJ8xrWx6DZrWjaBu2jCAFFYpwO6AtS4KNcEewjf2w69ZO8qLqUUTnVQEC9BttpTA2CAuKciQxGZ23lDNo70FEuBpKUAAvWm4El1ALCUaD0L0462GwNhYKUKCYLUcwAFIAAlUEzxI84GelRroRbzGSbUCDGBhQJ6ORi5AWL4T66X0HSICdPNga6p6uuYcI61WjcwLguUdwAF5x5ippovsbRdB1NpXGL4H9Ec-WgsoMfJ+nqxZ5qnQ9GOheV+Atfh4NreJ6n6K433kB56PgOl86pmlHpzr6mWwRBCA1o+bgE4UwrVQA9zoOwfuD0NRIFgugGAn1voIKhogHAY00AQR0AjA+J8o4lUflsQSMcyoVTQX1MBfd1KDwJq3EAnROgIzxtaZQdD7BwAAI4MFmugNgEEIIN3wWgTwlAxCOkejA8wmkaBYxxg-Q+WwLB4LkYI4RQFMBsAOj0LS91BrkwuLLYCpcnyojmvLdAitwagWNqnaCyB16Z2UPwTOTBHFEXcDnPOiRT40PSCXBaOpNaMzlqDMxKDlZWMGjYjO6B7GOOcZnVx7j85M1RqAVm7NgamJACTeOvM2D8wVrhCAj1Or6WFl1MWA1I5oSMuYbChNglnyVpYuahi0Df1Wg4dam0QCmwOv7L4gt7A+zQA7OATsXZmXdoYT2zMw7KQjvxGOzsSkK00gZSJdiHFOJcSbJAO1BDa11uYGA4k2gQAABQpTStFfBWUACU18vDuAAPzJRHulI2WV3AJWirPK6V1AJlmaq1UYnglBiOeupdGxyEE-SwPYBhgMBqczBhDHJ0NzBwwRkjOAKMSppORZkpe+NoTQVkLigASkgHq8M0A2AUsA92FhqoYDgEg-iIiOrlN6qAKpOianPwKpVIJk02jTRVp0tWfUjYAAVqUVNQPwQoSy47ryYInNRKcDF+LaStd+eyMJ+DwmXKIMZk5ICUugzBYyDHnXMhgwQWCekGsEAAGV6HQKqhC1QOSlroty9gpq4pltAT+lVUbyj6XdUBche4QMoefdAVzR6PNvhYe+Aj0BL3cmWKhF9N7bxvkiDNSi24n0dHmpNI8r471vjYEtOC8ov3kIoxt8l4F8T-iBPJgDGXd1jeA+u2iIUwq+nC5B2NSEOqdZmhRzNM2CQBZUOQCFxagCQF05Fhi-YW0GUBYg6E1J9X-j2gpYEikahWf8oAA)